# Showing that the only roots of a ploynomial are $x=0, y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am trying to show that the only roots of the following polynomial: $$x^2-xy+4y^2$$

Are x=0 and y=0

But I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 4):

Complete the square. A sum of squares is zero only if each term is zero.

Comment: What do you mean by 'complete the squares'?

Comment: @SylvesterStallone : $x^2- xy=x^2-2x\frac y2$ is part of a squared binomial.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2-xy+4y^2=\left(x-\frac12y\right)^2+\frac{15}{4}y^2$$
is the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\neq0$, let $y=ax$.

$$x^2-xy+4y^2=0$$
$$x^2-x(ax)+4(ax)^2=0$$
$$x^2(1-a+4a^2)=0$$

For $1-a+4a^2=0$, $\Delta=(-1)^2-4(1)(4)<0\implies\text{No (Real) Roots.}$

Therefore the only solution is $x=0,y=0$.

Comment: You can only do this assuming $x\neq 0$. If $x=0$ this is clear, but still one has to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view this polynomial as a quadratic function of $x$. Then the discriminant would be $Δ=y^2-16y^2=-15y^2$. As a result, there are no real roots for $x$, unless $y=0$, which yields $x=0$.